# How to query a "history" table to find what value was valid at a certain date for a join

Tags: mysql

I've got a table `history` that holds a factor and the timestamp when it was changed and to what zone it belongs like so:

```
zone_id | validity_period_start | factor
--------+-----------------------+-------
 1      | 1970-01-01            | 50
 1      | 2000-03-03            | 70
 2      | 2000-02-02            | 90
 3      | 2005-08-08            | 20
 3      | 2010-10-10            | 30
```

I've got another table `report` with reports for the zones with dates like so:

```
report_date | zone_id | value
------------+---------+------
2005-09-09  | 1       | 500
2005-09-09  | 2       | 300
2005-09-09  | 3       | 200
2005-09-10  | 1       | 600
2005-09-10  | 2       | 700
2005-09-10  | 3       | 900
```

Now I want to do a
`SELECT * FROM report WHERE report_date BETWEEN ( "2005-09-09" AND "2005-09-10")`
and `JOIN` the `history`.
I want the value and ideally the `product = value*factor` in the return table based on the `history.factor` that was valid at the `report.report_date` like so:

```
 report_date | zone_id | value | factor | product |
 ------------+---------+-------+--------+---------+ 
 2005-09-09  | 1       | 500   | 70     | 35000   |
 2005-09-09  | 2       | 300   | 90     | 27000   |
 2005-09-09  | 3       | 200   | 20     | 4000    |
 2005-09-10  | 1       | 600   | 70     | 42000   |
 2005-09-10  | 2       | 700   | 90     | 63000   |
 2005-09-10  | 3       | 900   | 20     | 18000   |
```

---

For your convinence the examples create code:

```
CREATE TABLE rikai_history
(zone_id INT, validity_period_start DATE, factor INT);
INSERT INTO rikai_history VALUES
(1, "1970-01-01", 50),
(1, "2000-03-03", 70),
(2, "2000-02-02", 90),
(3, "2005-08-08", 20),
(3, "2010-10-10", 30);

CREATE TABLE rikai_report
(report_date DATE, zone_id INT, value INT);
INSERT INTO rikai_report VALUES
("2005-09-09", 1, 500),
("2005-09-09", 2, 300),
("2005-09-09", 3, 200),
("2005-09-10", 1, 600),
("2005-09-10", 2, 700),
("2005-09-10", 3, 900);
```

Comment: Well done. Exactly how a question should be asked (except you haven't really shown us what you've tried). Presumably there's only one factor per zone_id/validity_period_start? And only one value per zone_id/report_date

Comment: Which factor should be taken from `history` ?

Comment: Why isn't the first row of the history table taken? Also, why isn't the last row taken? I guess I just asked the same question as Code-Monk.

Comment: @Code-Monk: Always the factor that was valid at the time of `report.report_date`

@McAdam331: Because e.g. for `report.report_date="2005-09-09"` and `report.zone_id=1` the first row of `history` with `history.factor=50` is invalid because since `report.report_date="2000-03-03"` the valid factor is `history.factor=70'

Comment: @Strawberry: I deliberatly left out my attempts, I ran into the issue the last time I asked a question that I got an awesome but overcomplicated answer because it was biased by my attempt to solve the issue. Still learning mySQL as a language it's just like learning a real language. Listen to someone who knows how to form easy, understandable sentences and analyze them =) Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a PRIMARY KEY is formed on both (zone_id,validity_period_start) and (zone_id,report_date)...

```
SELECT x.report_date
     , x.zone_id
     , x.value
     , y.factor
     , x.value*y.factor product 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT r.*
            , MAX(validity_period_start) max_start 
         FROM rikai_report r 
         JOIN rikai_history h 
           ON h.zone_id = r.zone_id
          AND h.validity_period_start <= r.report_date 
        GROUP 
           BY r.report_date,r.zone_id
      ) x 
   JOIN rikai_history y 
     ON y.zone_id = x.zone_id 
    AND y.validity_period_start = x.max_start ;
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct, those form the primary key. Sorry forgot to mention it.